# Can I test ASP.NET MVC 2 for Mono on Windows before deploy to Linux?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono

Is it possible and Is there something special to do for that ?

Comment: Did you mean to ask _how_ to do this, rather than _if_ it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

First, you install the Mono-Framework.

Then you open cmd.exe and go to the root directory of your web application (the folder where web.config is in).

There, you start xsp/xsp2/xsp4 (this assumes that the mono-framework folder containing xsp/xsp2/xsp4.exe is in your path environment variable), 
then you start Google-Chrome (or your favourite webbrowser [I will hope this isn't IE]) and go to http://localhost:8080

There, you either see your website, or a YSOD.
If you want to be totally sure, you do this in a VM where the .NET Framework is not installed.

Comment: @user310291: MVC 3 might require mono 2.10.